# Typescript copying only function arguments and not return type

Tags: typescript

I have some util methods and I'm wondering if there's a way to copy arguments from one method to another.  I was playing around with `typeof` and trying to type the 2nd function that way but I can't quite figure it out.

```
declare function foo(a: number, b: string): number;
```

now I want a type `bar` to have `foo`'s arguments, but not the return type, for example let's say it calls foo but doesn't return anything:

```
const bar = (...args) => { foo(...args); }
```

Now I can declare `bar` to have the exact same type as `foo`:

```
const bar: typeof foo = (...args) => { foo(...args); }
```

but the return type doesn't match now.  So how do I either:

- Just copy the argument signature
- Change the return type I get from `typeof foo`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's built-in [Parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1474) type

```
declare function foo(a: number, b: string): number;

type fooParameters = Parameters<typeof foo>;

declare const bar: (...parameters: fooParameters) => void;
// inferred as const bar: (a: number, b: string) => void
```

Comment: in my case I wanted just the first parameter, for this you can do `Parameters<typeof foo>[0]`. In the end, `Parameters<>` returns a tuple.